# Ajax request not working using differnt version of php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I moved my project from one computer to another and now one of my ajax requests is not working.  The php version on the first computer is 7.2.4 the new computer is 7.3.6 that is the only difference I can come up with.  I am using the same exact files I just copied them over.  the project is on PHP using jquery to do an ajax submit request using PDO.  . I can only think it is the XAMPP server our the PHP however the versions are not far apart.
Thanks
Jon

I tried using procedural PHP and It still would not submit

there is no error message

Comment: AJAX requests are triggered from the browser and has nothing to do with the server side code. If you say `not working`, you need to mention details on what is expected, what is not, may be some errors, warnings and associated code for us to help.

Comment: Sounds like a possible javascript side error. Did you also check the browser console?  (could be something as simple as a syntax error with jQuery, maybe) Beyond that, we'd need more info, as Panther has suggested.

Comment: If you use Google Chrome, press F12, go to "Console" tab, click to send form and tell us what you see in Console window.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: this is what I get from the console Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/razzdigital/private/css/bootstrap.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.css.map

Comment: Check the host name, or use absolute path in url at ajax request. Prefix a '/' before url of your ajax request.